# Is the table locked when multiple queries are executed against an indexed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In MS-SQL Server, a table is not locked when a read query is selecting only one row. In a multi-threaded environment, is the table locked when multiple queries of the same kind are executed at the same time? Let me explain it through an example.

The table won't be locked since we're selecting only single record

```
select * from Employees where EmployeeId = 1234
```

### Multi-threaded Environment:

```
select * from Employees where EmployeeId = 1234 
select * from Employees where EmployeeId = 5678 
select * from Employees where EmployeeId = 9012 
select * from Employees where EmployeeId = 3456
```

Will this affect data manipulation if read/write occur at the same instance?

Please note that the EmployeeId column is indexed.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, with your queries using an index seek to a single row, no table or page locks will be taken until a threshold of concurrent locks is exceed, I believe it's around 5000.

Comment: @Stu Don't forget `IS` table locks, which are used to allow a later upgrade to a full table lock

Answer (score 0):

No the whole table will not be locked.  Depending on the configuration and isolation level these queries will either take no locks at all or shared row/key locks.

This is a rather large topic, though, and you should read the [Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide)

Comment: I'd love to know how you take *no locks at all*, at the very least a `Sch-S` lock is taken. And for sure the whole table can be locked: a row or page `S` will also take an `IS` lock on the table in case it gets upgraded to a full table `S` lock, which happens often

Comment: I was simplifying by omitting the shared schema lock and intent locks.  And lock escalation shouldn't happen with a selective predicate.